# Docker how to run mongodb in dockerfile

Tags: mongodb, docker, boot2docker, dockerfile, docker-compose

I have a dockerfile that runs a maven build. I am following this guide: https://hub.docker.com/_/maven/

So far in my dockerfile I have this: `FROM maven:3-jdk-8-onbuild`

It runs the build and fails as expected because the integration tests require that the mongodb server on the localhost is running.

My question is, what do I write in the dockerfile to create an image that has mongodb, start it before the integration tests, and stop the mongodb server after the integration tests?

Thanks

Comment: have a look at supervisor https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/

Comment: `supervisord` would start the child processes in parallel. In that case you would never know whether the *mongodb* service is already up and running when the maven build needs it or not. For that build it must be assured that *mongodb* is started first. So you need something sequential. I described an idea in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run in addition to the other statements in your `Dockerfile` statements to install *mongodb*.

As a template you could for instance use the instructions from the [tutum/mongodb](https://hub.docker.com/r/tutum/mongodb/~/dockerfile/) `Dockerfile`.

Then instead of using the `mvn` command directly you could call a *shell script* instead in which you start mongodb first, then execute `mvn` and as a last step stop mongodb.

Comment: I followed the guide https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/ exactly (except using ubuntu:14.04 instead of 13.04) and I am getting this error: supervisord.conf: no such file or directory

Comment: Then you missed the line `COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf` instruction in your `Dockerfile`. But why are you using `supervisord`, now? In my answer I wrote nothing about it. In my comment on your question I explicitly mentioned why *not* to use `supervisord`.

Comment: If you use `supervisord` you start *mongodb* and *maven* parallel. You _never know_ whether *mongodb* is already up and running when the maven build reaches its integration tests. Therefore it is better to sequentially do those steps. First start mongodb and wait until it is up. Then run maven. And at the end shut down mongodb again. Those steps can be done in a shell script that you execute instead of `supervisord`.

Comment: I read your answer to my other question. It worked thanks. I wanted to see how supervisord works. Now as for the shell script you are talking about, how would I write the script?

Comment: and the shell script can be invoked with the CMD key word?

Comment: sorry im new to docker

Comment: The shell script will then be invoked by `CMD` instead of `mvn`, yes.

Comment: I see. And how do you write this shell script, I've never done it before? can you direct me to some resources pls?

Comment: If you want to avoid shell scripting you could do it a bit different. You could use `supervisord` indeed. But then you need to implement a "wait for mongodb" step *in your maven build* before you start your integration tests which simply checks for the availability of the mongodb network port.

Comment: Ahh I see, I will take a look at the maven wait step. Thanks for the help, I will mark both questions as answered.